# Creating a fifo queue in SQS using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto3

Can anyone help me with creating a fifo queue in sqs using boto3. Tried this but this doesn’t work

```
sqs.create_queue(QueueName='test', Attributes={'FifoQueue':'true’})
```

Comment: Did you see the tutorial - http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs.html ?

Comment: @MattM there are not a single word about FIFO queues. However there is some explanation here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.ServiceResource.create_queue

Comment: @pt12lol I was only asking the OP if he had seen the tutorial/guide, not implying that the answer was there. It looks like he got the answer he was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your queue name has to end in `.fifo` and you have to be using either `us-west-2` or `us-east-2` region as those are the only regions that currently support the FIFO feature.

Comment: This helped. Even though the regions thing is mentioned in one of the pages, it's not very emphasized in the developer guides, nor is included in boto3 docs.

Comment: us-east-1 also supports fifo queue

Answer (score 8):

This is a complete working example of creating a FIFO queue on SQS:

```
import boto3
import pprint

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name='us-west-2')

queue = \
    sqs.create_queue(QueueName='test.fifo', Attributes={'FifoQueue': 'true'})
pprint.pprint(queue)
```